# Modify a PDF created with LaTeX after compilation

Tags: editors, latex-misc, workflow, wysiwyg

In my working group we are currently mainly using Word and PowerPoint. Which is a pity, after we have three different OS's in operation. And every time we send files in between, the layout is shifted, or other things are not working anymore (even between OS X Word and Windows Word, let's not talk about LibreOffice). Same goes for formulae (Physics/Math related work) in papers and posters.

I would like to switch to LaTeX for the whole group, but the biggest counter argument I get is that then you can not directly edit files you receive. The usual working process is that you get a `.doc` file, directly write your comments in it (or modify the text yourself) and send it back. Is something similar also possible for LaTeX? Or am I stuck with annotations in the PDF, and the creator has to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: no.

A slightly longer answer:

I think you are mixing up a few things here -- which is no surprise as the problem involves MS Word which itself mixes up the content and formatting layer, as well as the editing and presentation layer when used in the usual wrong way. This last statement may hold at least when it comes to an external communication process. (For internal revisions it's totally fine, at least in my eyes, to send around `.doc`s like you mentioned in your post.)

But(!): the analogy is inapropriate. The `.doc` is the manuscript from which you can and usually should create a `.pdf` when publishing content. Transferred back to LaTeX you would say that the `.tex` file is your manuscript from which you are able to compile into publishing compliant file formats like PDF and DVI. Thus, your colleagues argument is simply invalid. You can edit LaTeX files directly, in the right layer, apparently.

Long story short: No matter which program you are dealing with, a `.pdf` is a presentation file and it should not be up for discussion if you are able to modify it.

I guess what you are really looking for is a WYSIWYG platform for the LaTeX format. For this you may have a look at [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/). It can't handle `.tex` files directly. It has an own tag set and markup, but a `.lyx` file gets interpreted to the LaTeX format and compiled by a TeX engine.